# Loading node modules failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

I created an ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio 2017 with Angular 2,
installed node.

package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "webpack-script": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "-vs-binding": {
    "BeforeBuild": [
      "webpack-script"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.16",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.5",
    "ts-loader": "^2.3.5",
    "typescript": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.5.6",
    "concurrently": "2.2.0",
    "systemjs-builder": "0.15.32",
    "json-server": "0.8.21",
    "jsonwebtoken": "7.1.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "html5-history-api": "^4.2.8",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "popper": "^1.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^3.5.6"
  }
}
```

systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
    var map = {
        'app': 'app', // 'dist',
        '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [ // <-----
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router',
        'router-deprecated',
        'upgrade',
    ];
    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    };
    // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    }
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

_Layout.cshtml in the head section I added

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<base href="/" />
<title>@ViewData["Title"] - LanguageSchool.Web</title>

<environment include="Development">
    <script src=@Url.Content("~/node_modules/html5-history-api/history.min.js")></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/classlist.js/classList.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/intl/dist/Intl.complete.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="rxjs.module.min.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import("app/main").catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
    <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
```

But when I try to load the page I get a number of errors:

> Loading failed for the  with source
>   “https://localhost:44341/node_modules/html5-history-api/history.min.js”.
>   localhost:44341:10 Loading failed for the  with source
>   “https://localhost:44341/node_modules/classlist.js/classList.min.js”. 
>   localhost:44341:11 Loading failed for the  with source
>   “https://localhost:44341/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js”. 
>   localhost:44341:12 Loading failed for the  with source
>   “https://localhost:44341/node_modules/intl/dist/Intl.complete.js”. 
>   localhost:44341:13 Loading failed for the  with source
>   “https://localhost:44341/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js”. 
>   localhost:44341:14 Loading failed for the  with source
>   “https://localhost:44341/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js”. 
>   localhost:44341:15 Loading failed for the  with source
>   “https://localhost:44341/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js”. 
>   localhost:44341:16 Loading failed for the  with source
>   “https://localhost:44341/rxjs.module.min.js”.  localhost:44341:17
>   Loading failed for the  with source
>   “https://localhost:44341/systemjs.config.js”.

**Updates:**
main.ts

```
window["$"] = window["jQuery"] = require("jquery");

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).
    then(success => console.log('Bootstrap success')).
    catch(error => console.log(error));
```

app.modules.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.components.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    template: `<div class="bg-success p-a-1 text-xs-center">
This is SportsStore
</div>`
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Comment: how did you get the start package?  **CLI?**, did you **download** it from any page? did you **restore** packages? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular2/angular2_hello_world.htm

Comment: @VictorHugoTerceros sure, npm install. All the package exist in the node_modules directory. Updated the question with the typescript code

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source paths you set. Your compiler can not find the files.
You haven't set them properly.

```
 <script src=@Url.Content("~/node_modules/html5-history-api/history.min.js")></script>
<script src="./node_modules/classlist.js/classList.min.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/intl/dist/Intl.complete.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="rxjs.module.min.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import("app/main").catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
</script>
<link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
```

Comment: Hi Jetblack, your answer has typo and there is no further references to help to solve the question. please try to minimize typos by review it before submit. try to add links to background your  answers.

Comment: Then you haven't installed the node modules. http://dotnetdetail.com/how-to-setup-angular-2-with-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: @jetblack I did install then, they physically exist in the node_modules